# onloadeddata event on img tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to execute javascript function after img tags have finished loading the content of the image.
I looked at the W3C website and it is said the the onloadeddata event could do this and is assignable to img tags.

```
<img src="image.jpg" onloadeddata="onThumbMouseOut(this);"/>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work and I checked with the Javascript debbuger that my function was not called.

Do you know where I am wrong?

Comment: Where on the W3C site did you see this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp
In the Media Events Section

Comment: W3Schools is a [pretty terrible](http://www.w3fools.com/) tutorial site and has no connection with the W3C. They enjoy basking in the reflected glory of having a similar name though.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadeddata.asp

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I naively tought there was a connection ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the onload attribute

```
<img src="http://link_to_image" onload="alert('LOAD')" />
```

Answer (score 4):

That event is for audio / video. For images you can use onload instead.